# Browse Array with a particular point

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a forward button and I'm traversing an Array with some data. I can already advance normally, but now I need to move forward from the item determined.

```
public int mIfCounter = -1;
public String [] mAlphaArray = {279, 278, 277, 276, 275, 274, 273, 272, 271, 270, 269, 268, 267, 266, 265, 264, 263, 262, 261, 260, 259, 258, 257, 256, 255, 254, 253, 252, 251, 250};
```

Example number I want to start:

```
String stringPosition = "272";
```

Button next:

```
buttonNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mIfCounter < mAlphaArray.length - 1){
                mIfCounter++;
            } else {
            }
            Log.i("INFO", mAlphaArray[mIfCounter]);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I'm not sure what do you need? You can write an example?

Comment: I am creating an option to advance number. Then in case I need to determine the starting point. There he is traversing the Array normally, but I want to walk from a certain point that would be "272".

Comment: "Starting point" you refer the position for value 272? Bone the number 272 has the position 7

Comment: That. But this number will be different, it will always change. So I can not find his position by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get index of your starting point with:

```
int stringPosition = Arrays.asList(mAlphaArray).indexOf("272");
if (stringPosition >= 0) {
    // String positioned in the list, use it
}
```